# NSTableView reducing width of included NSPopUpButton

Tags: nstableviewcell, nspopupbuttoncell

I have a NSPopUpButton in a NSTableCellView in a NSTableView. I set the PopUp in IB to the full width of the Column. Running the app, the width of the popup is reduced by 30% on the right side, leaving space in the column and truncating the text.

PopUp in IB:
[image: PopUp in IB]

PopUp in app:

[image]

The size of the popup is Small, but setting to Regular takes no effect, nor does increasing the witdh of the cellview or the column.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: Add autolayout constraints?

Comment: does not change anything, but thanks.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: I finally found the reason for that behaviour: In the viewFor-function I identify the popup with an identifier. I subclassed the NSTableCellView to add the PopUpButton, but I set the identifier of it in each column to the same value - copy-paste. So every popup had the same origin. Giving the popups in evers column their own identifiers solved the issue. Thanks.